Error when calling class constructor with Python in Vscode
enter image description here
class CircularlyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

.
.

When I ran the above code and entered:
ls1 = CirculralyLinkedList()
An error occurred: An expression must come after '('.
This error did not occur when running with IDLE.
If I need to type something after '(', please tell me what to type.

You entered the line into the terminal, not the Python REPL.

Just entering in the REPL also does not fix the problem because the class is not defined in the REPL unless you import it from the file or type it in there

You enter python code directly in the cmd terminal, which is not recognized. You need to enter pythonREPL.
You could try the following ways:

You could use jupyter-notebook extension, and the class codes to cell1 and ls1 = CirculralyLinkedList() to cell2. This way you can achieve the same goal when you execute cells sequentially
Try to use python interactive window, this way is similar to the first solution.
Use pythonREPL and re-import class

